# Is this property true for infinite limits of integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

This property is true:

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\mathrm{d}x=-\int_{b}^{a}f(x)\mathrm{d}x $$

Does that mean that the following is also true:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\mathrm{d}x=-\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}f(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: yes, it is. More precisely, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx$ is shorthand for $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \int_{-n}^n f(x) \ dx$ and you can see that in the second form there is no reason you cannot swap the limits.

Comment: @DougM This is the Cauchy principal value. It does equal $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ whenever this integral converges, but it is somewhat misleading to say that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ is shorthand for $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-n}^n f(x)dx$, because the latter may converge while $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ diverges. That said, your explanation is good for when the integral converges.

Comment: @Snaw Fair enough.  I should have indicated different indices, one with a limit going to $+\infty$ and the other going to $-\infty$

Comment: @Snaw can you give an example for $f$ that results in $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-n}^n f(x) dx$ converging while $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ diverges?

Comment: @RadialArmSaw Take any odd function $f(x)$ for which $\int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx$ diverges. For instance, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x dx$ diverges, but $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-n}^n x dx = 0$.

Comment: @Snaw thanks.  Now I understand.

Comment: I would say that $\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ is merely notation for $-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm{d}x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f
\\:=&\lim_{a\to-\infty}\int_{a}^{0}f+\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{0}^{b}f
\\:=&\lim_{a\to-\infty}\left(-\int_{0}^{a}f\right)+\lim_{b\to\infty}\left(-\int_{b}^{0}f\right)
\\=&-\left(\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{b}^{0}f+\lim_{a\to-\infty}\int_{0}^{a}f\right)
\\:=&-\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}f.\end{align}

P.S. The convention $$\int_{a}^{b}f:=-\int_{b}^{a}f,$$ which this question is premised on, ensures that for each $p,q,r\in\mathbb R,$ $$\int_{p}^{r}f=\int_{p}^{q}f+\int_{q}^{r}f.$$

P.P.S. Alternatively, as suggested by GEdgar's above comment, we can simply *adopt as convention*  $$\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}f:=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f.$$

Comment: I thought it is worth making this explicit: the last equality is a definition. We define the symbol $\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}f(x)dx$ to mean $\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_b^0 f(x)dx + \lim_{a\to-\infty} \int_0^a f(x)dx$. If we do not make this definition (or another one, like $\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$) then no proof can show anything about the value of the symbol $\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}$.

Comment: @Snaw Come to think of it, my postscript is a red herring, and _both_ the first and final equalities prior to that are definitions. As such, GEdgar's comment above is totally pertinent. Agree?

Comment: Which one? I might be missing something but I think it's all correct except noticing that the last step is to be made a definition. The first equality is the usual definition of the symbol $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$. The second equality uses $\int_a^b=-\int_b^a$ which is also true by definition for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. The third equality is limit arithmetic. Only the last one seems to me to be the one requiring further explanation.

Comment: If we define $\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ then your explanation shows that we also have the usual decomposition we'd expect to have, $\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} = \int_{\infty}^a + \int_a^{-\infty}$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$. So your explanation links the two forms, and seems like we could make either one of them a definition.

Comment: @Snaw Yes; I've just been editing the answer in parallel with your latest comment. Thanks for your input.