# Is it valid to say that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx = \lim_{t\to \infty} \int_{-t}^t f(x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

So, I'm a college freshman, and when I was doing a homework problem, I found that the definite integral was equal to zero. It was an integral of the form $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$ and $f(x)$ happened to be an odd function. I never questioned whether the property of odd functions,
$\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx = 0$ still works when a is infinity instead of a finite number. But my intuition and that homework problem I did seem to suggest that.

My reasoning to justify the idea is that for an odd function $f(x)$,
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx = \lim_{t\to \infty} \int_{-t}^t f(x)dx = \lim_{t\to \infty} 0 = 0.$

This argument only works if the first step is valid. I'm wondering if there are any problems with it since you usually deal with this kind of improper integral as two integrals: $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^a f(x)dx + \int_a^\infty f(x)dx$.

Comment: If you happen to know that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx$ exists. Otherwise... not so much. Otherwise, you would get $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x dx=0$.

Comment: What you’re calculating is known as the Cauchy Principal Value. Unfortunately, without making a restriction like this, you have to treat the upper and lower bounds as *separate* limits.

Comment: We recently had a related discussion, in which [Snaw's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4388933/is-this-property-true-for-infinite-limits-of-integration/4388973#comment9176348_4388933) directly addresses your question and gives the classic counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I see the difference between them now.

Comment: It would be good to have this question with an answer (not merely a comment).  Provided it is not already a duplicate question.  (Is it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the [Cauchy Principle Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), the integral of an odd function across the real numbers is probably zero
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty o(x)dx=0,$$
where $o(x)$ is an odd function

But an improper integral across all the real numbers does not actually exist if we cannot split it. In other words,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$$
does not converge unless
$$\int_a^\infty f(x)dx \ \ {\rm and } \ \ 
\int_{-\infty}^a f(x)dx
$$
both converge for every $a$.